# Aggregate dataframe by dimension pairs for heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, heatmap

I have a table with rows being individual visits from users to an online shop. There are multiple columns that are attributes of the visit (could be booleans or categorical with more than 2 possible values). And there is a column that counts how many items were bought during that visit.

I want to create a table which summarises by every attribute-pair the average number of items bought per visit. I.e. for a given attribute pair value, sum up the number of items bought and divide by the number of rows for this attribute pair. I would then use this table to visualise it as a heat map.

*This is similar to preparing separate heatmaps for every attribute-pair. But would want to do this in one table or heatmap for easier digestibility.*

*Note than along the diagonal when the same attributes are being compared the result is always 1, or when mutually exclusive attributes are compared the result is NA. The cells left empty are the same as the ones filled in above the diagonal.*

Input table:

| visit_id | age | is_website | is_US | items_bought |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | young | true | true | 0 |
| ab | young | false | false | 2 |
| ac | old | true | true | 0 |
| ad | old | true | false | 3 |

Desired output table:

|  | age young | age old | is_website true | is_website false | is_US true | is_US false |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| age young | 1 | NA | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| age old | NA | 1 | 1.5 | null division | 0 | 3 |
| is_website true |  |  | 1 | NA | 0 | 3 |
| is_website false |  |  | NA | 1 | null division | 2 |
| is_US true |  |  |  |  | 1 | NA |
| is_US false |  |  |  |  | NA | 1 |

**What I tried:**

1. hard code a list of the attributes (i.e. column names that are attributes)

```py
data = {
    'visit_id': ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'],
    'age': ['young', 'young', 'old', 'old'],
    'is_website': [True, False, True, True],
    'is_US': [True, False, True, False],
    'items_bought': [0, 2, 0, 3]
}

import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

dim = ['age', 'is_website', 'is_US']
```

2. create a list of all the unique attribute pairs without repetition using `combinations` from `itertools`

```py
from itertools import combinations
dim_pairs = list(combinations(dim, 2))
```

3. run a for loop:

- group the dataframe by the attribute pairs, sum up the items bought (`total_items_bought`) and count the number of rows (`total_visits`)
- add a new column to the resulting dataframe `items_bought_per_visit` which is `total_items_bought / total_visits`
- Save the resulting dataframe to a dictionary

```py
dfs = {}

for x in range(len(dim_pairs)):
    grouped = df1.groupby([dim_pairs[x][0], dim_pairs[x][1]]).agg({'items_bought': 'sum', 'visit_id': 'count'}).reset_index()

    grouped['items_bought_per_visit'] = grouped['items_bought'] / grouped['visit_id']

    pivot_df = grouped.pivot_table(index=dim_pairs[x][0], columns=dim_pairs[x][1], values='items_bought_per_visit', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)

    df_name = f"pivot_df{x}"
    dfs[df_name] = pivot_df
```

So I have a dictionary of dataframes which has all the values I'd need to fill in the single desired output table, but not sure how. Or not sure if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to first reshape `df1` with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), then use [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) with a custom function:

```
tmp = (df1
   .melt(df1.columns.difference(dim))
   .assign(variable=lambda d: d['variable']+' '+d['value'].astype(str))
   .pivot(index='visit_id', columns='variable', values='items_bought')
)

def f(a, b):
    m = a == b
    return a[m].mean()

out = tmp.corr(f)
```

Output:

```
variable          age old  age young  is_US False  is_US True  is_website False  is_website True
variable                                                                                        
age old               1.0        NaN          3.0         0.0               NaN              1.5
age young             NaN        1.0          2.0         0.0               2.0              0.0
is_US False           3.0        2.0          1.0         NaN               2.0              3.0
is_US True            0.0        0.0          NaN         1.0               NaN              0.0
is_website False      NaN        2.0          2.0         NaN               1.0              NaN
is_website True       1.5        0.0          3.0         0.0               NaN              1.0
```

Intermediate `tmp`:

```
variable  age old  age young  is_US False  is_US True  is_website False  is_website True
visit_id                                                                                
aa            NaN        0.0          NaN         0.0               NaN              0.0
ab            NaN        2.0          2.0         NaN               2.0              NaN
ac            0.0        NaN          NaN         0.0               NaN              0.0
ad            3.0        NaN          3.0         NaN               NaN              3.0
```